# How to make GridView Slidable?

Tags: android, gridview

I am making project in which i want the items in the GridView must be slidable as in the game 2048. I made a layout using GridView now i want it to be slidable from top to bottom, bottom to top, right to left and left to right. What must i do so that it becomes slidable?

In the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,
        OnDrawerOpenListener {

    GridView gridView;
    SlidingDrawer sd;

    static final String[] numbers = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
        // sd = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.sDrawer1);
        // sd.setOnDrawerOpenListener(this);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `GridView` like scroll horizontal/vertical. Then in that case the **Two-Way View** will be helpful to you. Which is an Android `GridView` that can be configured to scroll horizontally or vertically.

Check out the [Link 1](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) and [Link 2](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) which provides the demonstration of GridView in two way.

Comment: i tried to import those projects so that i may study the but they were not getting imported